# How to make round segment divider in donut chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i have tried to make
[image: my donut chart] look like svg , without using svg . bcz in angular, i did'nt find any donut chart , that look like [image: this chart]  ,
i did find one chart , but that was in jquery and i cant use jquery. how can i make round edges of segment divider of this multilevel donut chart
i'm using chart.js 4 in angular .

Here is the example  .

```
 var config: any= {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
              data: [
                
                {
                  value: 50,                 
              },
              {
                  value: 50,                 
              }
                  
              ],
                  backgroundColor: [
                  "#ff3333",
                  "#660000",                
              ],
                  hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#ff3333",
                "#660000",
              ],
              hoverBackground: NONE_TYPE,
              borderColor:NONE_TYPE,
              hoverBorderColor:NONE_TYPE,
              borderWidth: 0,
              datalabels : {
                display: false
               }
             
          }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
              data: [
                {
                  value: 70,                  
              },
              {
                  value: 30,
              }
              ],
                  backgroundColor: [
                  "#00ff00",
                  "#003300",
               ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#00ff00",
                "#003300",
             ],
              
               borderColor:NONE_TYPE,
               hoverBorderColor:NONE_TYPE,
               borderWidth: 0,
               datalabels : {
                display: false
               }
               
          }, {
            label: 'Dataset 3', 
              data: [
                {
                 value:40,                    
              },
              {
                value:60,                  
              }
              
               ],
               labels: [
                'green',
                'yellow',
              ] ,
               backgroundColor: [
                  "#1991EB",
                  "#001f4d",
               ],
               hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#1991EB",
                  "#001a4d",
              ],
              
               borderColor:NONE_TYPE,
               hoverBorderColor:NONE_TYPE,
               borderWidth: 0,
               datalabels : {
                display: false
               },
               
               
          }], 
        
          
      },
      options: {
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            display: false
          },           
                
        
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rounded ends of the arcs in a doughnut or pie chart are covered by the [borderRadius](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/charts/doughnut.html#border-radius) option.

If we choose the radius of that rounded end to be 15px we can write that as

```js
    datasets: [{
        //..... data and other dataset options
        borderRadius: [
            {outerStart: 0, outerEnd: 15, innerStart: 0, innerEnd: 15},
            0
        ]
    }]
```

Obviously, to round the other end, one should set `outerStart` and `innerStart` values.
The second value of the `borderRadius` array (zero) corresponds to second value of the dataset, which stands as the background of the stripe.

Here's a snippet with your data

```js
const data = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [50, 50],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#ff3333",
            "#660000",
        ],
        borderRadius: [
            {outerStart: 0, outerEnd: 15, innerStart: 0, innerEnd: 15},
            0
        ],
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [70, 30],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#00ff00",
            "#003300",
        ],
        borderRadius: [
            {outerStart: 0, outerEnd: 15, innerStart: 0, innerEnd: 15},
            0
        ],
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    {
        label: 'Dataset 3',
        data: [40, 60],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#1991EB",
            "#001a4d",
        ],
        borderRadius: [
            {outerStart: 0, outerEnd: 15, innerStart: 0, innerEnd: 15},
            0
        ],
        borderWidth: 0,
    }]
};

const chart = new Chart(document.querySelector("#myChart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data,
    options: {
        cutout: 60,
        responsive: true,
        radius: "80%"
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="max-height:350px">
<canvas id="myChart" style="background-color: #000"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

There are a few problems with this:

- the background is not perfect, under the rounded ends there's the canvas background, not the second color that's supposed to e the stripe background
- the second item, that should act as a background is also producing a tooltip on hover, that needs to be disabled
- the radius of the rounded end has to be preset, and a resize of the canvas may get to inadequate values (although an update can be implemented).

To cover these cases, I implemented a custom `DoughnutController`, see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/developers/charts.html), called `DoughnutWithRoundEnds`, with id `doughnut_round_ends`, that extends the standard `doughnut` with three dataset options:

- `roundStart` and `roundEnd`, (default value `true` for each), a boolean for each value (no need to set the border radius, it is computed automatically taking into account the current size of the arc when drawn)
- `overallBackgroundColor` - the inactive background color of the stripe - which will allow to use just one value in combination with setting a [`circumference`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/charts/doughnut.html#general)

```js
const _drawArcElement = Chart.ArcElement.prototype.draw;
class DoughnutWithRoundEnds extends Chart.DoughnutController{
    static id = "doughnut_round_ends";

    updateElements(arcs, start, count, mode) {
        super.updateElements(arcs, start, count, mode);
        const dataset = this.getDataset();
        const overallBackgroundColor = dataset.overallBackgroundColor ??
            this.options.overallBackgroundColor;
        let roundEnd = this.getDataset().roundEnd ?? this.options.roundEnd ?? true;
        if(!Array.isArray(roundEnd)){
            roundEnd = Array(arcs.length).fill(roundEnd);
        }
        let roundStart = dataset.roundStart ?? this.options.roundStart ?? true;
        if(!Array.isArray(roundStart)){
            roundStart = Array(arcs.length).fill(roundStart);
        }
        if(overallBackgroundColor && roundEnd.length > 0){
            arcs.forEach((arc, i) => {
                let borderRadius = 0;
                if(roundEnd[i] || roundStart[i]){
                    const r = Math.ceil((arc.outerRadius - arc.innerRadius)/2),
                        rStart = roundStart[i] ? r : 0,
                        rEnd = roundEnd[i] ? r : 0;
                    borderRadius = {
                        outerStart: rStart,
                        outerEnd: rEnd,
                        innerStart: rStart,
                        innerEnd: rEnd
                    };
                }
                if(i === 0 && overallBackgroundColor){
                    arc.draw = function(ctx){
                        const backgroundColor = this.options.backgroundColor,
                            startAngle = this.startAngle,
                            endAngle = this.endAngle;
                        this.options.backgroundColor = overallBackgroundColor;
                        this.options.borderRadius = 0;
                        this.startAngle = 0;
                        this.endAngle = 2*Math.PI;
                        _drawArcElement.call(this, ctx);
                        this.options.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                        this.startAngle = startAngle;
                        this.endAngle = endAngle;
                        this.options.borderRadius = borderRadius;
                        _drawArcElement.call(this, ctx);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    this.options.borderRadius = borderRadius;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

Chart.register(DoughnutWithRoundEnds);

const data = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [50],
        circumference: [50/100*360],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#ff3333"
        ],
        //roundStart: [true], //default
        // roundEnd: [true], // default
        overallBackgroundColor: "#660000",
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [70],
        circumference: [70/100*360],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#00ff00"
        ],
        overallBackgroundColor: "#003300",
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    {
        label: 'Dataset 3',
        data: [40],
        circumference: [40/100*360],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#1991EB",
        ],
        overallBackgroundColor: "#001a4d",
        borderWidth: 0
    }]
};

const chart = new Chart(document.querySelector("#myChart"), {
    type: 'doughnut_round_ends',
    data,
    options: {
        cutout: 60,
        responsive: true,
        radius: "80%",
        //roundStart: false // for all datasets
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="max-height:350px">
<canvas id="myChart" style="background-color: #000"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

This version also works with two (or more) values, as in the first case, if the second one is relevant and isn't just for the background: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2fhvrsw/).

Comment: thank you very much for your help , i had given up this task , bcz it was seeming impossible to me .

Answer (score 0):

check out chartjs-plugin-datatlabels packages if you still working on it.

https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/